# Bootstrap: Make column size always 12 on small device but default behaviour on other devices

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I have a component that that can hold a variable number of elements.

What I want is to make the element align one under another and take the full container width
when the screen is small, but have the default Bootstrap column behaviour in larger screens.

I want something like this:

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-12 col">/div>
 <div class="col-sm-12 col">/div>
 <div class="col-sm-12 col">/div>
 .
 .
 .
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: bootstrap should push items under eachother based on screenwidth already, can you show us your code you tried?

Comment: do you want your element full width in large screen also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `col-md`

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-12 col-md">s</div>
 <div class="col-sm-12 col-md">s</div>
 <div class="col-sm-12 col-md">s</div>
 .
 .
 .
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thaks!

Comment: never believed some one would ask question in my mind, never believed some one would answer it, never believed it would work... . thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lets take the example you have 3 column you want to show them one beside another and on mobile screen you want to show them one under another.

This will be the code

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">/div>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">/div>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">/div>
</div>
```

The column length depend upon the column number you want to show

Check the link for more details.
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Only use `col-sm`, then the colums will be full width on mobile (xs)..

https://www.codeply.com/p/ovXfFNTSce

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm"> . </div>
    <div class="col-sm"> . </div>
    <div class="col-sm"> . </div>
    <div class="col-sm"> . </div>
</div>
```